# AVPlayer - Auto quality change - Multiple URLs

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer, videoquality

I have multiple URL for different video quality (240p, 360p, 720p, 1080p) and i'm using AVPlayer to stream. What i wanna achieve is

Selecting initial URL to start video depending on internet connection speed (I don't have concern with wifi, 2G or 3G; only concern is that connection speed is able to stream or not)
Switching URL/Stream while playing if internet connection speed is updated.
Video should not pause while auto switching URL/Stream
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're duplicating the effort of HTTP Live Streaming. Can you just adopt that?

https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Comment: I couldn't get that. Can you please explain? I saw another post like that as well, but couldn't understand.

Comment: I'm saying that HLS is probably what you want. The URL you point to isn't the video file. It's a manifest - a text file describing several aspects of the video -- including different bitrates that are available. Also, the videos are typically broken up into small, 10-second segments instead of trying to stream a full video. AVPlayer decides which videos to download based on connection speed and other criteria. I'd go on, but it's all available at the link provided. It's a pretty good solution, well with established, and widely adopted.